# Yocto: _append python code to a shell task

Tags: python, shell, mingw, yocto, bitbake

I want to append a non-trivial python code to the "do_install" task, which is shell code.

How can I do that? Can I just use the following, and it magically will work?

```
python do_install_append() {

}
```

What's the best workaround? Use the `[postfuncs]` attribute? Or create an entirely new task and add it after `do_install` before `do_package`?

**Goal**:

I'm porting some packages to be able to build for `MACHINE=x86-64_mingw32`. Some packages install their `.dll` files into `${libdir}`, but for MinGW the correct folder for shared libraries would be `${bindir}` (according to other build systems like MSYS2 and MXE), so my class will automatically move entire sub-trees out of `${libdir}` into `${bindir}`, after the recipe's `do_install`. Afterwards, if this leaves any empty folders in `${libdir}` where the shared libraries used to be in, they will be removed.

Comment: `python do_install_append(){}` will magically work. Is it much more complex than just create a standard `do_install_append_x86-64_mingw32(){ mv ${D}{libdir}/* ${D}${bindir}/; rm ${D}${libdir}}` ?

Comment: @Nayfe Richard in his answer disagrees.

Comment: Richard Purdie is the lead Architect of the Yocto Project, listen to him :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An append won't magically work, postfuncs would be the best way to handle it. That said, could you set libdir to point at bindir using an override within the recipe?:

```
libdir_x86-64-mingw32 = "${bindir}"
```

That might work better...

Comment: Hmm, then it will install the dev files, like the static libs also to bindir, which is not wanted. It's messy. Thanks for the answer. I'll accept if nothing surprising happens.